# iOS Password based encryption using MD5 and DES : invalid ASCII string returned

Tags: ios, encryption, md5, nsdata

I am using a Password based encryption using MD5 and DES, below is function which i am using.

```
+(NSData*) cryptPBEWithMD5AndDES:(CCOperation)op usingData:(NSData*)data withPassword:(NSString*)password andSalt:(NSData*)salt andIterating:(int)numIterations {

unsigned char md5[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
memset(md5, 0, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);

NSData* passwordData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CC_MD5_CTX ctx;
CC_MD5_Init(&ctx);
CC_MD5_Update(&ctx, [passwordData bytes], [passwordData length]);
CC_MD5_Update(&ctx, [salt bytes], [salt length]);
CC_MD5_Final(md5, &ctx);

for (int i=1; i<numIterations; i++) {
    CC_MD5(md5, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, md5);
}

size_t cryptoResultDataBufferSize = [data length] + kCCBlockSizeDES;
unsigned char cryptoResultDataBuffer[cryptoResultDataBufferSize];
size_t dataMoved = 0;

unsigned char iv[kCCBlockSizeDES];
memcpy(iv, md5 + (CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH/2), sizeof(iv)); //iv is the second half of the MD5 from building the key

CCCryptorStatus status =
CCCrypt(op, kCCAlgorithmDES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, md5, (CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH/2), iv, [data bytes], [data length],
        cryptoResultDataBuffer, cryptoResultDataBufferSize, &dataMoved);

if(0 == status) {
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:cryptoResultDataBuffer length:dataMoved];
} else {
    return NULL;
}
}
```

The string returned is "`¯Â<˜˚mOm¢$—Ì7lÁ'9’G@.P`"

There are two question I am having:-
1) Is the above string a valid output for the above function. If not, then what is the issue with the function?
2) If yes, then why I am not able to decrypt the above string?

Comment: Hash functions are not reversible and as such are not encryption functions. Consider hashing a 1MB file, the result for md5 is 16 bytes. obviously data is lost.

Comment: If you are going to use cryptograph to obtain a secure result you need to understand cryptography and it's primitive operations. Or hire a cryptographic domain expert.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Is the above string a valid output - yes, it is valid. But not in the way that you are trying to print it.
2. why I am not able to decrypt - because there's a symbol-loss when you are representing encrypted data with `NSString`

If you need string representation of encrypted data, then you would go for Base64 representation of data.

In iOS 7 new method was introduced in `NSData` class: [`-[NSData base64EncodedStringWithOptions]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/base64EncodedStringWithOptions%3a) that is very useful for this purpose. To decode base64 string into `NSData` back, you want to use [`-[NSData initWithBase64EncodedString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithBase64EncodedString%3aoptions%3a) init method.

P.S. it is always helpful to have 3rd-party tool to compare results of your encryption with another output. The best approach is to use terminal-based encryption. But in most cases, online encryption tool would serve good enough.

Edit:

At first I didn't realised that you actually were trying to revert MD5 hashing. Most of hash functions are not backward-compatible, so they cannot be reverted. See the references for [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_function) and [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5)

Comment: I encrpyted the string in base64 format, but i am not able to decrpyt successfully.
The decrypt string is coming out different from the original one.

Comment: Wait. You are trying to reverse MD5 Hash?

Comment: @SandeepDhull most of hash functions are not backward-compatible, so they cannot be reverted. See the reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing_function

Answer (score 0):

Its a valid output. Try converting the string to base64 and then print it.